# Why do items keep loading after window.onload?

Tags: onload, pagespeed, onload-event

After running some tests on webpagetest.org, I notice about a third of the items load after the window.onload event.

I'm trying to understand why window.onload fires before the browser finishes loading all of the resources.

My hunch is that window.onload fires only when the resources included in the initial source code finish loading. So for example window.onload would include the time it takes to load the Google Tag Manager container (since the snippet is included in the source code) but any scripts loaded via Google Tag Manager wouldn't delay window.onload because they weren't included in the initial source code.

Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

the window.onload event represents the *window's* load event. other items may load after the window has been loaded.

Comment: So what technically gets counted as being part of the window?